# UIActivityViewController's twitter item - change post action on "post"

Tags: ios, xcode, post, twitter, share

is there a way to perform/override a different action on twitter's post popup when pressing "post" button ?

My code:

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:imgPath]];
NSArray *activityItems = @["Here is a gif image",imgData];
UIActivityViewController *activityController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems
 applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: I have a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259955/replace-uiactivityviewcontroller-twitter-post-action-with-a-slrequest), any one can answer?