# Replace UIActivityViewController twitter post action with a SLRequest

Tags: ios, twitter, gif, uiactivityviewcontroller, slrequest

I am trying to share an animated GIF but default UIActivityViewController Twitter share [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076737/1902782) it yet which it will "scale down" it as a still JPG, I have to use SLRequest for it as taught in [this article](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com.au/2016/01/how-to-using-slrequest-to-upload-image.html). The downside of that is no preview share sheet and users cannot type their own message anymore.

However, I saw [SteppyPants](http://steppypants.com/) that it seems using a custom action after users click "share" in Twitter share sheet, how can they do it?

In other word, how to replace the UIActivityViewController twitter share action to a custom action which includes SLRequest.

Things I tried:

- UIActivityItemProvider and check UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, but
  that's run after user click twitter and before editing the text
- In UIActivityViewController completionWithItemsHandler delete the just twitted post (with still gif) and post again with SLRequest, but not too sure if I can delete the old post and it's consuming network bandwidth for users anyway
- SLComposeViewController, does not support animated GIF upload and not custom share action at all

P.S. I am iOS newb

[image: UIActivityViewController share options]
[image: Replace custom action to share sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UIActivityItemProvider and check UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, but that's run after user click twitter and before editing the text

That's pretty close!

I believe Steppy Pants is doing what you said; providing a `UIActivityItemProvider` to the  `UIActivityViewController`, but with a twist.

When the `UIActivityItemProvider`'s `item` method is called, it checks if the `UIActivityType` is `UIActivityTypePostToTwitter` and if so, the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed and a custom `SLComposeServiceViewController` is presented.

If you look closely you can see: The presented view controller doesn't have a title and the remaining character count doesn't respond correctly to URLs. The `SLComposeServiceViewController` object then implements `didSelectPost` to present a spinner UI while it initiates an `SLRequest`.

Comment: Looks well-explained answer!

It has been a while so I moved on something else, will definitely come back and test it out!